# Given the below code about Deadlock...why deadlock is not happening here and what changes should i make to occur the deadlock

Tags: java, output, deadlock

```
public class Test15_DeadLockUsingJoinMethod {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        JoinThread1 jt1=new JoinThread1(jt2); 
        JoinThread2 jt2=new JoinThread2(jt1);
        jt1.start();
        jt2.start();
    }

}

class JoinThread1 extends Thread {

    JoinThread2 jt2;
    public JoinThread1(JoinThread2 jt2) {
        this.jt2=jt2;
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("1st thread execution start");
        try {
            jt2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("1st thread execution stopped"); 
    }
}

class JoinThread2 extends Thread {

    JoinThread1 jt1;
    public JoinThread2(JoinThread1 jt1) {
        this.jt1=jt1;

    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("2nd thread execution start");
        try {
            jt1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            System.out.println("2nd thread execution stopped"); 
    }
}
```

Here I want to see the deadlock condition using only `join()` method. I know the deadlock code using synchronized keyword. But how can we execute deadlock condition using join method?

Comment: Does this code compile? You are using `jt2` in the constructor of `jt1`, before it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn´t compile, you are using `jt2` in the constructor of `jt1`, before it is defined.

In order to get a deadlock, you should define a new constructor for `JoinThread1` that do not have any parameter. So, you first define jt1 using the new constructor. Then you define jt2 passing through parameter jt1 (like you have now). Then you should define a `setter` for the other thread in JoinThread1.

***Example:***

**New constructor**

```
public JoinThread1() {
}
```

**Setter method**

```
public void setThread(JoinThread2 jt2){
    this.jt2 = jt2;
}
```

**Main**

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

```
    JoinThread1 jt1=new JoinThread1(); 
    JoinThread2 jt2=new JoinThread2(jt1);
    jt1.setThread(jt2);

    jt1.start();
    jt2.start();
}
```

After that changes,you will get a deadlock.